# How to open/convert a .xmdx file?

Tags: file-extension

I have a file that was sent to me with a `.xmdx` extension. Is there any way to convert it to something readable or open it with a third party application? I have never seen a file like this before so I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: I've checked a number of file type extension databases and have come up with nothing; not even close spellings. without more info on the source of the file or its content, can't say much more.

Comment: What are the first dozen bytes of these xmdx files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xmdx files are the encrypted back-up answer files produced by the examination-taking software called SofTest, often used in law schools for essay examinations.  I know of no way to open them that does not involve using SofTest as an examination-administrator.